# What term is used to describe when something "only interests a very narrow group"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term used to describe when something, such as a college class or book, is something that might only interest a tiny group of people?

"Nerdy" seems to be the nearest word I can find, but it has too much of a negative connotation. Is there something similar, without the negativity?

Sample sentences:

```
English 408: Existential Literature is a class that is too _____, so few students signed up.

Only a few students joined the Klingon language club, because it is too ____.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word for not obscure but not mainstream](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/345410/word-for-not-obscure-but-not-mainstream)

Comment: Avoid word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for an adjective. Formal or informal. Are these the sentences you are actually writing. Is "nerdy" the only word you've considered. Have you searched existing Q&A here or elsewhere.

Comment: Your sample sentences could work with a great many adjectives meanly fairly different things - your title wording could limit that to directly mean "only interests a narrow group" but you back that off a bit to make other types of words that describe a trait of the topic 'specific', 'detailed' , 'unusual', or 'odd' as a secondary effect. "Nerdy" brings it away from the subject to "nature of someone who it would appeal to" instead of "nature of ~what~ they are appealed to" fine distinction opening a third idea. "unusual" and "specialized" are different things Kangaroo vs Optometrist ?

Answer (score 3):

'**Esoteric**' suits, I believe :

> requiring or exhibiting knowledge that is restricted to a small group; esoteric terminology; broadly : difficult to understand esoteric subjects

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/esoteric)

> Japan’s ‘forest bathing’ treatment: Burnout stopper or **esoteric** fad?

[Borneo Bulletin - 15th May 2018](https://borneobulletin.com.bn/japans-forest-bathing-treatment-burnout-stopper-or-esoteric-fad/)

Answer (score 1):

**Specialized** would be a good word here. The EOD has:

> specialized (British specialised) adjective
>
> 1 Requiring or involving detailed and specific knowledge or training.
>       ‘employees with specialized skills’
>
> 1.1 Concentrating on a small area of a subject.
>       ‘periodicals have become more and more specialized’
>
> 1.2 Designed for a particular purpose. ‘specialized software’

The concentration on a small area of a subject results often in a "**niche**" market, defined, as an adjective, as:

> Denoting or relating to products, services, or interests that appeal
>   to a small, specialized section of the population.

[EOD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/english)

Answer (score 0):

Could be you are looking for 'factional'. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/factional

Comment: Another possibility might be 'narrow'. EBT

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [niche](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/niche).

> 3. A specialized segment of the market for a particular kind of product or service.
>
> ‘he believes he has found a niche in the market’
> ‘smaller cooperatives must find and develop a niche for their speciality product’