# Is there a word meaning "not popular enough"?

Tags: single-word-requests

We have a word "underrated", which essentially means "not liked enough". I was wondering if there was a single word meaning "not popular enough". When searching online, the only word that came up was "unknown". As far as I can tell, it doesn't exactly mean what I want - even though it means that few people know about something, there is no underlaying message that says "more people should know about it"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word for not obscure but not mainstream](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/345410/50044)

Comment: "Underrated" does not mean "Not liked enough".

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with an example of how you want to use this word?

Comment: The last part of the last sentence in your question -- *"more people should know about it"* -- actually makes me think **underrated** is the word you want.

Comment: **Single word requests should be accompanied by an example sentence showing how the word will be used.**

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think "underrated" means "not liked enough"? It doesn't mean that, but if you explain why you think it does, and why it's not the word you're looking for, we may have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: 'esoteric' may work in some contexts

Comment: @Marthaª What do you think the ‘rating’ refers to in ‘underrated’?

Comment: As applied to what? A person, an album, a crestive work, a country...? The answer will depend.

Comment: The word _underpopular_ is underpopular.

Comment: @user3840170, the meanings of sub-parts of a word are about as relevant as its etymology, which is to say, not at all. A word means what people use it to mean, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: It's not a single word, and it's a noun rather than an adjective, but the term **Hidden gem** might describe what you're thinking of.

Comment: What you are asking for reminds me of the words in the song "Rocks in my bed" (I think written for Duke Ellington by Harvey G Cohen) most famously sung by the great blues singer, Bessie Smith:  "Underloved, overfed,/  my man's so instead / I've got rocks in my bed."

Comment: Unpopular. There is no between; one is either popular or unpopular. Stems from the origin of the word.

Answer (score 29):

Underappreciated (adj)

> not appreciated or valued enough
>
> "Her work is underappreciated by the critics. an underappreciated
> talent"

[The Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/underappreciated)

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted, it's the perfect answer.

Comment: Related: undervalued (if the OP is talking about an object)

Comment: @theonlygusti Because it is underappreciated

Comment: Because ‘underappreciated’ is nearly synonymous with ‘underrated’, from which the asker specifically wanted to distinguish.

Answer (score 27):

**overlooked** (adj.)

> Not seen, noticed, or considered
>
> *As well as revisiting the traditional narratives of politics and war, historians are now becoming more interested in previously **overlooked**
> histories—especially those of class and gender.* — Mary McAuliffe
>
> *But sometimes the simplest fixes are also the most **overlooked**.* — David Posey  [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overlooked)

---

> Two most **important** considerations should be mentioned at once,
> however; for they are almost uniformly **overlooked**, not only in the
> popular analysis, but also in the analysis of many psychologists.
> [George Ladd; *Outlines of Descriptive Psychology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Outlines_of_Descriptive_Psychology/cK4RAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=overlooked%20and%20not%20as%20popular&pg=PA309&printsec=frontcover) (1898)

> That the themes of recognition and identity have gone largely
> unnoticed in Mozart's *[La Finta] Giardiniera* is hardly surprising;
> they have also been **overlooked** in Mozart's later and more famous
> operas. [Jessica Waldoff; *Recognition in Mozart's Operas*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Recognition_in_Mozart_s_Operas/8Hk8DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=overlooked%20for%20more%20popular&pg=PA106&printsec=frontcover) (2006)

> Because they are often **overlooked** and deserve attention, in this
> book I spend more time describing cones and inconspicuous tree flowers
> than I spend describing conspicuous tree flowers. [Nancy Hugo; *Seeing
> Trees*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Seeing_Trees/gV7oteRUlugC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=overlooked%20and%20deserve%20attention&pg=PA62&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> Another founder undeservedly **overlooked** by Hollywood is James
> Monroe (1817–1825), perhaps because his presidency is associated with
> the Missouri Compromise of 1820, whose attempt to strike a balance
> between the number of slave and free states postponed sectional
> confrontation but ultimately made it inevitable. [Iwan Moran;
> *Presidents in the Movies*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Presidents_in_the_Movies/kcleAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=undeservedly%20overlooked&pg=PT16&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

Answer (score 7):

[*underexposed*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/underexpose#English), meaning 2 in Wiktionary:

> 1. (photography) To take a photograph using too small an exposure
> 2. To provide with insufficient publicity

You could equally well try *underrecognised* or *under-publicised*.

In some contexts, [*underrepresented*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/underrepresent#English) may be adequate, but this is a bit more of a stretch of meaning.

> 1. To represent something as being lower or smaller than is the case.
> 2. To give something insufficient or inadequate representation.

Answer (score 6):

[Obscure](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obscure)

> not known to many people:

I cite it because it is the word I see routinely used to refer to works that aren't as popular as the writer thinks they should be.

Comment: But "obscure" is also used for things that nobody thinks should be more popular.

Answer (score 3):

## Undiscovered

This gets used a lot in the music industry, but also elsewhere.

Undiscovered talent, or genius, means it is not *broadly* known, but ought to be better known. For example, radio stations for DJ's often want to present audiences with *undiscovered* artists.

This usage is different than undiscovered elements or planets, which are considered "discovered" once anyone knows about them.

Answer (score 0):

Unpopular

I'm sorry if this is an unpopular answer.

Adding the prefix "un" to the front of a word can reverse its meaning.

Suitable - Unsuitable
Available - Unavailable

Some words seem to lend themselves better to the reversal than others. According to a Google nhram search, unpopular was used more widely in books in the early 1900's than it is today. Hence my opening comment.

https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/z8mxrwx/articles/z3cjkty

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Unpopular&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CUnpopular%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please support answers with references from reputable sources, even if the word you suggest appears obvious to you.

Comment: "unpopular" just means "not popular", though; there's no sense here of something deserving to be more popular.

Answer (score 0):

If the sort of "popularity" you have in mind relates to making use of something, rather than simply being aware of it -- e.g., a word that you wish people would say more often -- you might say [***underused***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underused):

> : not fully used : having more potential than is currently being realized or utilized

(Or [***underutilized***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underutilized), which is essentially synonymous.)

Answer (score -2):

Well, having read the question a couple times, I gotta ask; In your context, is the "underrated" object discounted just because people don't **know** about it, or is it because they don't care and are ambivalent to it?

I mean, we can go straight to "***dislike***" or "***disapprove***" if no one cares for it, but if it is just because no one knows about it, then you can start looking at words like "***underground***", "***hidden***" or even "***obscure***" as proffered above.

HTH.

Answer (score -2):

Adjectives include (in decreasing order of severity), [**Ostracised**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ostracize) (“Exiled from a group by common consent”), [**marginalized**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marginalize) (“relegated to an unimportant or powerless position within a group”) and **sidelined**.

Nouns include [**pariah**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pariah) (“one that is despised or rejected,” although this was formerly used for a real group of people), [**outcast**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outcast) (“one that is cast out or refused acceptance, as by society”) or [***persona non grata***.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persona%20non%20grata) (“A person who is unacceptable or unwelcome.”)

A much milder phrase, for someone who doesn’t fit in, but is still allowed to participate, is “the odd one out.”